# Anova for multiple subgroups

Tags: r, anova, p-value, manova

To compare two models using `anova` in R, I can simply use `anova(model1,model2)` and conclude whether they are significantly different or not based on the p-value returned. However, currently I have data such that:

```
Cities     Localities     x1     x2     y1
City1           .          .      .      .
City1           .          .      .      .
City2           .          .      .      .
City2           .          .      .      .
City2           .          .      .      .
City3           .          .      .      .
City4           .          .      .      .
City4           .          .      .      .
City4           .          .      .      .
```

and so on. I want to show that there is variability between cities as groups without comparing the models for each subgroup pairwise. What can I do?

Will `anova(models)` where `models=c(model1,model2,...)` vector of fitted models corresponding to each city work? Or should I perform `anova` on the full dataset. In that case, how do I define the subdivisions?

Comment: Fit two models, identical except that one includes `Cities` as a factor. Then `anove` gives you what you want.

Comment: @Limey Oh! so `model1: y1~x1+x2` and `model2: y1~x1+x2+Cities`?

Comment: Yes. As you indicate yourself in your question. Note that this is valid if and only if `model1` is contained in `model2`.

Comment: @Limey it is. although, `Cities` does not have numeric entries and the model i'm using quantile regression to fit the models.